# Добавления текста в QTextEdit, QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlineedit, qtextedit

У меня есть форма создания нового персонажа.

Как я могу вставить текст в поле "Описание персонажа" и в поле "Имя персонажа" для их дальнейшего редактирования?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_newperson(object):
    def setupUi(self, newperson):
        newperson.setObjectName("newperson")
        newperson.resize(600, 600)
        newperson.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        newperson.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 62, 301, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(newperson)
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 231, 20))
        self.name.setObjectName("name")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 241, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.aboutpersontext = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(newperson)
        self.aboutpersontext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 171, 501, 241))
        self.aboutpersontext.setObjectName("aboutpersontext")
        self.image = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 271, 51))
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.makeperson = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.makeperson.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 420, 131, 51))
        self.makeperson.setObjectName("makeperson")
        self.preview = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.preview.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 420, 161, 51))
        self.preview.setObjectName("preview")
        self.result = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 570, 391, 20))
        self.result.setText("")
        self.result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.result.setObjectName("result")
        self.image_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 500, 271, 51))
        self.image_2.setObjectName("image_2")

        self.retranslateUi(newperson)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(newperson)

    def retranslateUi(self, newperson):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        newperson.setWindowTitle(_translate("newperson", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("newperson", "Имя исторической личности:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Создание новой исторической личности"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("newperson", "Введите его описание:"))
        self.image.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинку главную картинку"))
        self.makeperson.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить персонажа"))
        self.preview.setText(_translate("newperson", "Посмотреть текст"))
        self.image_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинки фантомов"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `setText(const QString &text)` Устанавливает текст редактирования текста.

Добавьте в конец две строки:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_newperson(object):
    def setupUi(self, newperson):
        newperson.setObjectName("newperson")
        newperson.resize(600, 600)
        newperson.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        newperson.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 600))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 62, 301, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(newperson)
        self.name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 70, 231, 20))
        self.name.setObjectName("name")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 401, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 130, 241, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.aboutpersontext = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(newperson)
        self.aboutpersontext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 171, 501, 241))
        self.aboutpersontext.setObjectName("aboutpersontext")
        self.image = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 271, 51))
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.makeperson = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.makeperson.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 420, 131, 51))
        self.makeperson.setObjectName("makeperson")
        self.preview = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.preview.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 420, 161, 51))
        self.preview.setObjectName("preview")
        self.result = QtWidgets.QLabel(newperson)
        self.result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 570, 391, 20))
        self.result.setText("")
        self.result.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.result.setObjectName("result")
        self.image_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(newperson)
        self.image_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 500, 271, 51))
        self.image_2.setObjectName("image_2")

        self.retranslateUi(newperson)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(newperson)

    def retranslateUi(self, newperson):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        newperson.setWindowTitle(_translate("newperson", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("newperson", "Имя исторической личности:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Создание новой исторической личности"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("newperson", "Введите его описание:"))
        self.image.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинку главную картинку"))
        self.makeperson.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить персонажа"))
        self.preview.setText(_translate("newperson", "Посмотреть текст"))
        self.image_2.setText(_translate("newperson", "Добавить картинки фантомов"))

        self.name.setText(_translate("newperson", "Имя персонажа для дальнейшего редактирования"))
        self.aboutpersontext.setText(_translate("newperson", "Описание персонажа для дальнейшего редактирования"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @khalinmaxim что не так?